# Python/C++ Remote TCP Socket

Tags: python, c++, sockets, azure, tcp

I am trying to connect to processes to each other over TCP sockets. I have done this successfully when both processes are running locally by doing on the client side (a python process):

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost", 11111))
```

The server side was written by someone else and is implemented in C++.

```
#define WIDTH 640
#define HEIGHT 480
#define DEPTH 3
#define BUFS (WIDTH*HEIGHT*DEPTH)
int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
socklen_t clilen;

void netx_setup()
{     
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = 11111;
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

     std::cout<<"Waiting for connection\n";
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
         if (newsockfd < 0) 
              {
                std::cout<<"No connection!\n";
                newsockfd=0;
              }
}
```

However, I now need to have the server process running on my local machine while the client is running on a Microsoft Azure VM instance. I have all of the necessary code in place to handle everything once the connection is made, but I'm not sure how to go about setting up the socket for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The server looks like it should work fine.  Just replace `"localhost"` with the address of your Azure host in your client code.  You may need to configure the firewall on your server to allow the remote connection, but how to do that seems more like a [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) question.

Comment: So what *specifically* are you asking?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I need to move the client process to an Azure VM. In doing so, I believe I need to modify the client process code so that it can still find the C++ server. I'm asking for guidance in modifying the client connection. Per Miles' suggestion, I've changed "localhost" to the IP address of my VM instance and enabled inbound/outbound traffic over my port, but the connection is still failing.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, based on my understanding, I think you want to deploy your C++ server process on your local machine and deploy the Python client on Azure VM, and make them communicate with each other. So it's a classic C/S communication model, you can make your client connect to server side if your local machine has a WAN ip. If not, you need to create an [Azure VPN Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways) to [create a Site-to-Site connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal) for communication with the two processes via their own VPN VIP.

Hope it helps.